# Additional text encountered after JSON reading

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Alabama"}
{"id":2,"name":"Alaska"}
{"id":3,"name":"Arizona"}
{"id":4,"name":"Arkansas"}
```

and this code:

```
string[] testDataFiles = new string[] { StatesOneFileName, StatesTwoFileName, ContinentsFileName };

foreach (var testFile in testDataFiles)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(testFile))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic jsonObjectArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        foreach (var item in jsonObjectArray)
        {
            expectedPartitions.Add(item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, however, I get this error:

```
Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0.
```

I've read a few StackOverflow suggestions to encase the test data in [], but unfortunately I cannot edit the json file itself. Is there a way to wrap something in my code such that it reads the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: Not to cause you further dismay, but aside from wrapping those lines in [ ] brackets, you'll probably also need to add a comma at the end of each line (except the last one) in order to make it valid json syntax.

Comment: Oops, yes, @JoeIrby is right. Ignore my first comment please ;) (deleted now)

Comment: As I understand you have multiple Json object if you can not change the input then parse each line separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a file that contains a json object per line, as follows:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Alabama"}
{"id":2,"name":"Alaska"}
{"id":3,"name":"Arizona"}
{"id":4,"name":"Arkansas"}
```

You can create the following model for your data:

```
public class State
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And then create a simple method that reads the file line by line, as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<State> GetStates(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Path to json file cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(path));
    }

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find json file to parse!", path);
    }

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
    {
        State state = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<State>(line);

        yield return state;
    }
}
```

Using the code:

```
string path = ".....";

// get the list of State objects...
List<State> states = GetStates(path).ToList();

// or just the list of state names
List<string> stateNames = GetStates(path).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your `json` file, it's not correctly formatted... You have multiple `json` objects in it, but it's neither enclosed in `[]` to show it's an array of `json` objects, nor are they delimited by comma.

The best thing you can do here, is to read line at a time, and convert it to `json` object, since it seems that each line represents one `json` object.

```
string json = "start";
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(testFile)) {
    while (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json)){
      json = r.ReadLine();
      dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
      //DO YOUR MAGIC HERE
     }
 }
```

Comment: Or you could do this in a cleaner way with `var names =  File.ReadLines(testFile).Select(line => JObject.Parse(line)["name"])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could easily fix the syntax errors in the json from that file, without modifying your existing code too much:

```
foreach (var testFile in testDataFiles)
 {
     // read the contents of the file with invalid json format, and build a new string named cleanJson with the fixed file contents
     string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(testFile);
     string cleanJson = "["; // add an opening array bracket to make it valid json syntax
     for (int i = 0; i < fileLines.Length; i++)
     {
         cleanJson += fileLines[i];
         if (i < fileLines.Length - 1)
              cleanJson += ","; // add a comma to the end of each line (except the last) to make it valid json syntax
     }
     cleanJson += "]"; // add a closing array bracket to make it valid json syntax

     dynamic jsonObjectArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cleanJson);

     foreach (var item in jsonObjectArray)
     {
         expectedPartitions.Add(item.name);
     }
 }
```